# Is $pr[x>a]=pr[x<-a]$ if $x$ is normally distributed and what if it is not.

Tags: probability

Is $pr[x>a]=pr[x<-a]$if $x$ is normally distributed, because of symmetry, and what if $x$ is not normally distributed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes by symmetry. This is usually not the case if your random variable isn't a mean zero normal distribution

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can accept the answer as a satisfactory one by adding a "tick" sign to it. It helps people know that the question has been properly answered!